# Какой лучше всего реализовать сканер штрих кода и qr кода?

Tags: java, android, xml

какой сканер лучше всего реализовать? Мне нужно чтоб по кнопке открылась камера и сканировался штрих код или qr код, я ужк использую zxing, но он не всегда корректно считывает даже можно сказать в большинстве случаев неправильно это делает. Например, беру штрих код, а он видит его как qr код. Или чуть какая потёртость или неровность то он считает не правильный набор цифр. Если есть возможность с кодом реализации или примером.

Comment: Я делал с помощью Google Mobile Vision. Меня все устроило. https://medium.com/@desai.krupa/quickly-detect-qr-code-with-google-mobile-vision-f0109c653182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный сканер работает со всеми форматами

https://github.com/brightec/KBarcode

Вся информация
https://github.com/brightec/KBarcode/wiki